# Simple Class test does not pass

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I am newbie of JavaScript. I am learning about Class with testing by Jasmine. I tried to clear the test, but despite of my efforts, Jasmine does not show green.

My code is below:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
var Animal;

Animal = (function() {

  function Animal() {}

  Animal.prototype.walk = function() {
    return 'tok tok...';
  };

  return Animal;

})();
```

And the test code is below:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3

describe("Animal", function() {
  var animal;
  animal = new Animal;
  it("shold walk", function() {
    expect(animal.walk).toBe('tok tok...');
  });
});
```

And the message from Jasmine is below:

```
Expected Function to be 'tok tok...'.
Error: Expected Function to be 'tok tok...'.
    at new jasmine.ExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:102:32)
    at null.toBe (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1194:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/__spec__/AnimalSpec.js:8:25)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1024:15)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2025:31)
    at goAgain (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2015:18)
```

I am exhausted. Thank you for your kindness...

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute the function, compare the result of the function to a string, not the function itself.

```
expect(animal.walk()).toBe('tok tok...');
```